# How I can delete some characters of a line upto one particular character using shell scripts

Tags: file, shell

I have a file called output.txt and it caontains a line "test[1,2,3]: [x+y=0]"
I want to delete all the characters upto '['. and delete ']' as well. I want to have only x+y=0 in output.txt using shell script. I can not delete some fixed no. of characters from the beginning as this output.txt is generated dynamically. Please provide some solution.

Comment: is Powershell an option?

Comment: I am using linux os.

Comment: Then [edit] your question and add that information there where it can be seen, instead of hiding it in the comments.

Comment: Do you want to delete all characters up to the second '['found? Will your file follow always the same pattern? Like abc[xxx]: [blabla]?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell:

`$teststring=teststring.replace("[", "").replace("]", "") -replace ".* "`

Answer (score 0):

This will split your row based on the ':' delimiter and take the second token and with that I then replace blank space and '[' and ']' characters with nothing:

```
cat output.txt | cut -d':' -f2 | sed -e "s/ //g; s/\[//g; s/\]//g"
```

Prints:

x+y=0